# Can someone explain to me how this function using sum works?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sum

```
def no_six_in_range(start, end):
    print(sum('6' not in str(i) for i in range(start, end + 1)))

no_six_in_range(6, 12)
```

"The sum() function returns a number, the sum of all items in an iterable."

So my question is, how would the sum work in this equation as sum adds the iterables together. But when you run the code it gives a lower number than the numbers given. If someone could explain this to me, it would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the expected and actual outputs from this function?

Comment: It just gives you the number of numbers in the range that do not have digit 6 in their decimal representation.

Comment: A less cryptic way to do the same would be: `sum(1 for i in range(start, end + 1) if '6' not in str(i))`

Answer (score 5):

This just counts numbers without any digit `"6"`. Note that the iterable here is the entire generator expression `expr_a for expr_b in expr_c`. The values that are being summed here (`expr_a`)

```
'6' not in str(i)
```

are `bool` values (`True` or `False`). `bool` is a subclass of `int`, so summing over them is summing over a bunch of `1`s and `0`s.

Compare e.g.:

```
>>> True + True
2
```

Answer (score 2):

if you run this code:

```
def no_six_in_range(start, end):
    print(list('6' not in str(i) for i in range(start, end + 1)))

no_six_in_range(6, 12)
```

you get:

```
[False, True, True, True, True, True, True]
```

so, if you sum them you will get 6 as each True is 1 and False is 0

Comment: Perfect! Thankyou.

Comment: @Ky1p please accept the answer, if you find it useful.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation right now to do that otherwise i would for all responses.

Answer (score 0):

According to the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions),

> 5.1.3. List Comprehensions
> List comprehensions provide a concise way to create lists. Common applications are to make new lists where each element is the result of some operations applied to each member of another sequence or iterable, or to create a subsequence of those elements that satisfy a certain condition.

The list comprehension evaluvates to a list, which like the sum funtion states, is an iterable.

The syntax is generally:

```
l = [ iterator for iterator in iterable ]
```

eg:

```
my_list_comprehension = [ i for i in range(10) ]
```

*Note that the first iterable and the second iterable can be different, so [ a for a in ARRAY ] and [ b for a in ARRAY ] both work as long as b is defined*

In this case, the code actually uses a *Generator* comprehension, which generates a generator instead of a list. A generator can also be iterated. The syntax for the generator comprehension is the same as that of a list, except that the [] is substituted for ().

So the

```
'6' not in str(i) for i in range(start, end + 1)
```

appends ( '6' not in str(i) ) to the generator as *i* goes through *range(start, end + 1)*

As the other answers explain, You can print out the arguments to figure out whats going on, like so:
[image: Testing the values with the interpreter]

And finally an array of booleans is converted by sum into integers and then added.

More info about [generators in python](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators).